# Report generation with PHP without a framework

Tags: php, html, report, reportgenerator, easyhtmlreport

I'm working on a university project , a web based systems to manage assets within a company.
I need to generate reports like repair and maintenance reports , asset level reports etc. The problem is, since it is a university project we are not allowed to use any frameworks or services which a available.
In that case is there a way where I could achieve this without a framework ?

Comment: report in pdf excel ?  can you add more proper details like core php or in laravel or asp ?

Comment: Core php
pdf of excels any format